# angular 2 changing component in time interval - carousel of components (not image)

Tags: css, angular, storyboard, report, carousel

There's a requirement, where reports of 10+ pages are displayed in wall board TV with each page displaying at a time. In every 5 seconds, different reports(page) is played like images keep changing in carousel or storyboard. What is the best way to work this out? 
The data source for the reports is SQL server which we can get by using web API. The data in the SQL server for this report changes every 24 hours so we have to make a new call to SQL server to refresh the data.

Answer (score 1):

Create an angular service which holds the data from your SQL server and refreshes it with  js "setInterval" ( https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp )
Then bind the UI to the service data and you're good to go.